# Can't use $match with mongoose and the aggregation framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my Schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,
  follow: [String],
  imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }

           }]
 });
```

And this is the code:

```
 usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){
  usermodel.aggregate({$unwind: '$imagen'}, 
                   {$match: { _id: { $in: user.follow } }}, 
                   {imagen: true}, 
                   {$sort: {'imagen.date': 1}}, 
                    function (err, images){

                     console.log(images);              

                      res.render('home.ejs', {

                       user: user,
                       following: images

                      });
   });
  });
```

The `follow` contains users's `_id`.

The code works, except when I include the `$match`. I use the `$match`to filter the result, only getting the images of the user that I'm following, but the console.log show me that the result of the `aggregate` search is undefined, but when I don't write the `$match` query, I get the images, but I obtain all the images, not only the images of the user that I'm following.

Is there any solution for this...?

Thank's advance!

EDIT:

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();
app.listen(9191);

var sessionStore = new MongoStore({db: 'session'});

app.configure(function(){

   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   app.use(express.cookieParser());
   app.use(express.session({
     store: sessionStore,
     secret: 'secret'
   }));
   app.use(app.router);

});

var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');

var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,
  follow: [String],
  imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }

           }]
 });

var usermodel =  db.model('usermodel', userschema);
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

app.get('/', middleware.noses, function (req, res){

     res.render('home0.ejs');

});


app.get('/home', middleware.yeses, function (req, res){

  usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){

    if (user.follow.length != 0){

      usermodel.find({ _id: {$in: user.follow } }, { user: true }, function (err, users){

         var usernames = users.map(function(u){ return u.user });

          usermodel.aggregate({$match: { _id: { $in: user.follow.map(
                                           function(id){ return new ObjectId(id); })}}},
                                       {$unwind: '$imagen'}, 
                                       {imagen: true}, 
                                       {$sort: {'imagen.date': 1}}, 
                                        function (err, images){

                                           console.log(images);

                                          res.render('home.ejs', {

                                             user: user,
                                             following: images

                                        });
               });
            });

    }  else {

       res.render('home.ejs', {

              user: user,
              following: undefined

            });

     }

 });
});
```

EDIT:

```
[ { __v: 4,
   _id: 50fd9c7b8e6a9d087d000006,
   follow: ['50fd9cbd1322de627d000006', '50fd9d3ce20da1dd7d000006'],
   imagen: 
   [{ title: 'foo',
      _id: 50fd9ca2bc9f163e7d000006,
      date: Mon Jan 21 2013 20:53:06 GMT+0100 (CET) },
    { title: 'foot',
      _id: 50fda83a3214babc88000005,
      date: Mon Jan 21 2013 21:42:34 GMT+0100 (CET) }],
   user: 'Mrmangado' }
```

Comment: You have you project `user` out before the unwind if you intend to use it after the unwind, edit: read too fast, you have to project the `_id` out

Comment: How do I project the `_id` out?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't do any schema-based casting of the arguments of `aggregate`, so you need to convert your `user.follow` array of string ids into an array of ObjectIds in the `$match`:

```
{$match: { _id: { 
    $in: user.follow.map(function(id){ return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id); })
}}},
```

<sup>NOTE: Do not use `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` for casting. **It will not work.**</sup>

You should also move this `$match` to the beginning of the pipeline for efficiency.

**UPDATE**

Your other problem is you need to use a `$project` operator instead of just including a plain `{imagen: true}` object in the pipeline.  Putting it all together and reordering for a more efficient pipeline, this worked for me with your data:

```
usermodel.aggregate(
    {$match: { _id: {
        $in: user.follow.map(function(id){ return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id); })
    }}},
    {$project: {imagen: true}},
    {$unwind: '$imagen'},
    {$sort: {'imagen.date': 1}},
    function (err, images){ ...
```

Comment: Stills returning undefined. Do I have to do something more?

Comment: @MrMangado Can you edit your question to include a sample doc or two?  The easier you make it for people to reproduce your problem the easier it is to fully answer it.

Comment: Update. I hope it would help

Comment: @MrMangado Thanks, but I was hoping you could include a sample `usermodel` document as well.

Comment: Updated! I hope it is what you asked for :)

Comment: @MrMangado Thanks, having the document was a big help.  See updated answer.

Comment: NOTE: The ObjectId constructor lives in two places: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` and `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`.  The latter was not working for me!  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thank you so much, I was about to waste multiple hours to figure out that my query was actually correct but gave a id instead of _id to the $in that removed all results...

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who stumbles upon this question hoping for a more 'generic' solution with the need to manually `.map` or do conversions/transformation manually, here a solution that `may` work for you:

**Requirements**: Your query object for the $match must fit into some schema you've created.

**General Solution**:

```
Model.aggregate([
   { $match: Model.where(yourQueryObject).cast(QueryModel); }
]);
```

The catch here is Mongoose Query API's [`Query#cast`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-cast) which can help you transforming your plain object into whatever the schema defines. This helps normalizing ObjectIDs, strings and numbers.

**Possible Solution to this Question**:

Considering only the $match phase:

```
{$match: usermodel.where({_id: { $in: user.follow }}).cast(usermodel) }}
```